# pandas df transformation: a better way than df.unstack().unstack()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transformation

Trying to convert pandas DataFrames from wide to long format.

I've tried to [`melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html), use [`wide_to_long()`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.wide_to_long.html) (the easy `melt()`), yet kept being confused with the syntax and the output I received.

I've also read through many posts on SO and the web about this topic and tried [quite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123924/convert-pandas-dataframe-from-wide-to-long) [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36763771/pandas-dataframe-to-long-format) [proposed](https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_long_to_wide.html) approaches, yet the results were never what I was looking for.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36537945/reshape-wide-to-long-in-pandas) helped me to discover `unstack()` - and I finally managed to get the result I wanted using it **twice in a row**: `df.unstack().unstack()`.

I'm sure that this is not the best way to do this and was hoping for a tip! Here's my example:

```
import pandas as pd

# an example df (the real data makes more sense):
series_list = [
    pd.Series(list("hello! hello!"), name='greeting'),
    pd.Series(list("stackoverflow"), name='name'),
    pd.Series(list("howsit going?"), name='question')
]

wide_df = pd.DataFrame(series_list)
```

Creating a df like that always gives me one in **wide** format:

```
          0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12
greeting  h  e  l  l  o  !     h  e  l  l  o  !
name      s  t  a  c  k  o  v  e  r  f  l  o  w
question  h  o  w  s  i  t     g  o  i  n  g  ?
```

However, I'd want the `pd.Series()`s `name=` attribute to become the **column names**.

What worked for me is the mentioned `df.unstack().unstack()`:

```
   greeting name question
0         h    s        h
1         e    t        o
2         l    a        w
3         l    c        s
4         o    k        i
5         !    o        t
6              v         
7         h    e        g
8         e    r        o
9         l    f        i
10        l    l        n
11        o    o        g
12        !    w        ?
```

But this sure is clunky and there must be a better way!

Thanks and have a good day : )

Comment: You simply need to transpose wide_df.T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `T`

```
wide_df.T
Out[1108]: 
   greeting name question
0         h    s        h
1         e    t        o
2         l    a        w
3         l    c        s
4         o    k        i
5         !    o        t
6              v         
7         h    e        g
8         e    r        o
9         l    f        i
10        l    l        n
11        o    o        g
12        !    w        ?
```

Comment: Oh my, yes! That's what I call an elegant solution. Wait... did I misunderstand long and wide format? (as in: does **transposing** even have anything to do with that?)

Comment: @martin-martin Yes you are  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22798934/pandas-long-to-wide-reshape, there is some example for long to wide .

Comment: @martin-martin also you can check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699653/using-column-name-as-a-new-attribute-in-pandas/45699937#45699937