# draw multiple box plots on a single graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

For a given dataset I am plotting a box plot of size of object at 10 different points as below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl

font_prop = font_manager.FontProperties( size=18)

def plot (path, name=""):
      df = pd.read_csv(path, index_col=0)
      df = df.dropna()
      Position = [1 + i // df.shape[0] for i in range(df.size)]
      df_n = [df[col] for col in df.columns]
      df_t = pd.concat(df_n).tolist()
      groups = [[] for i in range(max(Position))]
      [groups[Position[i] - 1].append(df_t[i]) for i in range(len(df_t))]

      plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5))
      plt.scatter(Position, df_t, color='g')
      b = plt.boxplot(groups, patch_artist=False)
      for median in b['medians']:
            median.set(color='r', linewidth=2)
```

A typical graph would be like this:
[image]

I have 4 different datasets and I would like to present a graph where on the position axis (x axis) there will be 4 bar plots  above each position. How would I modify my code to do that?

Here is the sample dataset:
https://github.com/aebk2015/multipleboxplot.git

```
,P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8,P9,P10,Class
1,7.6,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,6.0,49.0,1.0,1.0,40.0,L
2,9.7,2.7,5.6,1.0,1.0,1.0,34.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,L
3,1.0,6.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,3.0,39.0,1.0,28.0,1.0,L
4,8.0,25.5,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,24.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,L
5,1.0,29.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,38.0,29.0,20.0,1.0,L
6,4.0,34.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,39.0,14.0,1.0,12.0,1.0,L
7,1.0,17.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,20.8,1.0,14.6,1.0,L
8,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,19.0,17.5,1.0,1.0,L
9,1.0,30.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,3.0,23.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,L
10,1.0,5.0,25.0,1.0,1.0,17.0,6.3,1.0,17.0,1.0,L
1,11.8,19.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,11.3,2.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,C
2,12.0,17.0,20.0,9.0,1.0,23.0,4.0,7.0,1.0,1.0,C
3,14.0,30.0,8.0,1.0,11.0,24.0,38.0,1.0,3.5,1.0,C
4,10.5,10.4,11.5,20.5,1.0,22.0,3.0,15.0,5.6,3.7,C
5,1.0,13.5,8.0,6.6,1.0,37.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,4.0,C
6,12.4,22.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,29.0,17.0,11.0,1.0,1.0,C
7,1.0,43.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,10.0,18.0,8.6,1.0,1.0,C
8,15.0,12.0,1.0,35.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,10.0,3.0,1.0,C
9,1.0,24.0,8.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,4.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,C
10,4.6,2.0,7.4,1.0,1.0,22.0,5.6,1.0,25.0,1.0,C
1,1.0,39.0,11.0,13.0,1.0,1.0,28.0,7.0,1.0,7.0,W
2,8.0,52.0,22.0,10.0,1.0,1.0,33.0,13.0,1.0,4.8,W
3,1.0,28.0,1.0,10.0,1.0,1.0,24.0,3.0,1.0,4.0,W
4,8.8,11.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,W
5,1.0,42.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,69.0,1.0,31.0,1.0,49.0,W
6,9.0,36.0,11.0,14.0,24.0,1.0,8.0,1.0,1.0,15.8,W
7,13.0,33.0,12.7,8.7,1.0,1.0,7.8,38.0,1.0,1.0,W
8,1.0,36.0,12.0,1.0,1.0,12.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,W
9,1.0,10.0,12.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,64.0,13.0,1.0,14.0,W
10,8.0,31.0,19.0,1.0,24.0,1.0,48.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,W
1,1.0,9.7,6.8,53.0,1.0,57.0,1.0,9.5,1.0,1.0,B
2,5.8,16.3,1.0,10.8,1.0,58.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,B
3,1.0,38.0,17.0,34.0,1.0,55.0,1.0,8.0,1.0,1.0,B
4,1.0,42.0,1.0,26.0,1.0,1.0,65.0,44.0,1.0,1.0,B
5,41.0,43.0,16.0,9.7,1.0,36.0,61.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,B
6,47.0,20.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,28.0,7.7,1.0,1.0,B
7,22.0,92.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,20.0,15.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,B
8,31.0,72.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,20.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,B
```

Comment: This is not likely to get answered unless you add sample data (no images of data). I would used `sns.boxplot` which has a `hue=` option. A `'sample #'` column can be passed to `hue=` to separate the plots to 4 samples for each position.

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21232849/7758804) to read all the files in to a single dataframe with an identifying column.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Thanks for your comment. I tried seaborn but I am not sure how to define x1 and y1 in my dataset. I added a link to my sample dataset. Please see the last sentence in the question

Comment: I’m in bed, but from the look of the data, you need to .melt the dataframe. The class column should be set as id_var, the all the p columns will get melted to a long form. Once the dataframe is in a long form, it will work with seaborn

Comment: See [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C55GI.png). I'm not posting an answer, because everything is essentially a duplicate of other answers. However, if this is helpful, consider adding an upvote to those answer (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21232849/7758804, https://stackoverflow.com/a/36763815/7758804, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/69458847/7758804.

Comment: thank you very much! I wish you could post your answer here so someone else can use it but I did upvote the other post.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it worked for you.