# Two (top and bottom) pairs of boxplots, side by side

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn, boxplot

I currently get the following boxplot for my 4 datasets, which are to be compared horizontally.
Both ab and ba sets should be top and bottom (or overlapping if such is the data), while (gp-ab, mf-ab) and (gp-ba, mf-ba) should be side by side. However, I end up getting them all side by side, and not sure, how do I put only 2 pairs side by side.  (referred from [here, and others links present here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72932495/draw-multiple-box-plots-on-a-single-graph))

**All-sidebyside**:

[image]

Generated with the following,

```py
#Sea born bit
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

seed=3
legendclass = np.concatenate([['gp-ab']*seed,['mf-ab']*seed,['gp-ba']*seed,['mf-ba']*seed]).T.reshape(4, seed)
fid = legendclass.reshape(seed*(4)) #(seedx4)
pts = [[6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6.],
      [8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8.]]
rm_6 = array([34.97867074, 34.7816484 , 34.53641255, 15.37061205, 15.82006291,
       30.69718637, 15.15036871, 15.08025984, 17.3527419 , 17.46879552,
       33.28589986, 11.28854684])
df6 = pd.DataFrame({'fid-type': fid, 
             '6' : pts[0],
             'rmse-gp':rm_6})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
sns.boxplot(data=df6, x='6', y='rmse-gp', hue='fid-type', dodge=True, ax=ax, width=0.3)
```

How can I get the two pairs of top-bottom box plots and put them side by side?
PS: Also tried this with numpy code, but there, I couldn't get the horizontal spacing.

**With numpy**:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `sns.boxplot` twice for the same `ax`. Once for `ab` and once for `ba`. Using alpha transparency and two different color palettes helps to visualize the overlapping parts.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

seed = 3
legendclass = np.concatenate([['gp-ab']*seed, ['mf-ab']*seed, ['gp-ba']*seed, ['mf-ba']*seed]).T.reshape(4, seed)
fid = legendclass.reshape(seed * (4))  # (seedx4)
pts = [[6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6.],
       [8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8.]]
rm_6 = np.array([34.97867074, 34.7816484, 34.53641255, 15.37061205, 15.82006291, 30.69718637, 15.15036871, 15.08025984, 17.3527419, 17.46879552, 33.28589986, 11.28854684])
df6 = pd.DataFrame({'fid-type': fid,
                    '6': pts[0],
                    'rmse-gp': rm_6})
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
for abba, pal in zip( ['ab', 'ba'], ['autumn', 'winter']):
     df6_part = df6[ df6['fid-type'].str[-2:] == abba]
     sns.boxplot(data=df6_part, x='6', y='rmse-gp', hue='fid-type', dodge=True, ax=ax, width=0.3, palette=pal,
                 boxprops={ 'alpha':0.5})
```

[image: calling sns.boxplot twice]

Another approach is to split the `'fid-type'` column into two parts, use one for the x values and the other for hue:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

seed = 3
legendclass = np.concatenate([['gp-ab']*seed, ['mf-ab']*seed, ['gp-ba']*seed, ['mf-ba']*seed]).T.reshape(4, seed)
fid = legendclass.reshape(seed * (4))  # (seedx4)
pts = [[6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6., 6.],
       [8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8., 8.]]
rm_6 = np.array([34.97867074, 34.7816484, 34.53641255, 15.37061205, 15.82006291, 30.69718637, 15.15036871, 15.08025984, 17.3527419, 17.46879552, 33.28589986, 11.28854684])
df6 = pd.DataFrame({'fid-type': fid,
                    '6': pts[0],
                    'rmse-gp': rm_6})
df6['gpmf'] = df6['fid-type'].str[:2]
df6['abba'] = df6['fid-type'].str[-2:]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
sns.boxplot(data=df6, x='gpmf', y='rmse-gp', hue='abba', dodge=True, ax=ax, width=0.3)
```

[image: boxplot with two x and hue]

To make a distinction between 6 and 8, you could make an extra subplot for `8`.